# Creating Avro table with Buckets in hive

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, avro

I created a avro table with buckets but I face the following error:

> Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code
>   1 from       org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Bucket columns
>   uniqueid is not part of the table columns ([]

```
CREATE TABLE s.TEST_OD_V(
UniqueId int,
dtCd string,
SysSK int,
Ind string)
PARTITIONED BY (vcd STRING)
CLUSTERED BY (UniqueId) INTO 500 BUCKETS
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT                'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='s3a:/bucket/schema/pr_v.avsc');
```

I'm using hive 1.1. Kindly help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (avaliable from Hive 0.14):

`CREATE TABLE s.TEST_OD_V(
  UniqueId int,
  dtCd string,
  SysSK int,
  Ind string)
PARTITIONED BY (vcd STRING)
CLUSTERED BY (UniqueId) INTO 500 BUCKETS
STORED AS AVRO;`